# TimePicker Alignment in angular UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, timepicker

I have the following code:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu custom-scroll dropdown-label custom-width" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body"
                    ng-show="!display"
                    >
                    <li role="menuitem">
                        <a href="" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Start Time
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="timepicker1" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2"
                                       ng-model="abcd.startTime" ng-change="abcd.get('startTime')"

                                    />
                                <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="abcd.startTimeClicked = true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <timepicker ng-show="abcd.startTimeClicked" ng-model="abcd.startTime" ng-change="abcd.getETACount('startTime')" data-hour-step="1" data-minute-step="5" show-meridian="true" ></timepicker>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="menuitem">
                        <a href="" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">End Time
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="timepicker2" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2"
                                       ng-model="abcd.endTime"
                                       ng-change="abcd.getETACount('endTime');"
                                    />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"  ng-click="abcd.endTimeClicked = true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <timepicker ng-show="abcd.endTimeClicked" ng-model="abcd.endTime" ng-change="abcd.getETACount('endTime')" data-hour-step="1" data-minute-step="5" show-meridian="true" ></timepicker>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!--Clear div-->
                    <li role="menuitem" class="btn btn-default buttonli"
                        >
                        <a href="" ng-click="abcd.clearTimePicker($event);
         abcd.startTimeClicked = false; abcd.endTimeClicked = false">
                            <p>
                                <span class="clear-all-btn">Clear</span>
                                <span class="drop-down-clear">  – ETA</span>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

the following screenshot shows that the ":" (colon) in between hour and minute is not center aligned. But, If I try to center align it, all other table cell get impacted. How can I fix this?

[image]

AJS:1.3 version

Answer (score 0):

Have ever seen this website : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap ?
I guess so.

There is an example of timepicker (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker)

That may help you ? Or maybe you just wanna use timepicker tag ?

Hope it can helps.

Comment: What I meant is the alignment with AJS 1.3 is broken by using it